# Android studio default project fails: Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am literally just starting app development for the first time and the default project when I create a new one will not build. I have tried looking on Google and SO for these errors and have found some but their solutions do not work. Given that I have not edited the files at all, I presume it is an issue with Android Studio not being setup properly but can't figure it out. The errors are as follows:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

The build.gradle file it points to is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.extremecomputing.spotzz"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have tried with a previous project that I had created a few things I found online. Such as they had recommended the `+` in the version could cause unpredictable builds, but that wasn't it. One had recommended a few compile lines in the `dependencies` section, it changed the errors for a moment saying I needed to download something, I did then it went back to the original errors. I also have tried to make sure that the SDK tools are updated, and they appear to be. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the SDK Manager, did you install `Google Repository`?

Comment: What happens when you click on `Install Repository and sync project`?

Comment: Sometimes nothing, sometimes a screen will pop up with a download. Depending on which one I clicked on either the download would succeed or it would fail saying something about connection has been shutdown. I also just found this error from a blinking red exclamation mark in the bottom right of the screen: `Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed` This is not the exact error it was showing before, but close. Right now it's doing nothing when I click on it so I can't show the error.

Comment: You might need a proxy, or something, but in general, you'll need the repos before the dependencies can resolve

Comment: If you are referring to the line under SDK Tools > Support Repository > Google Repository, it says I have version 54 installed.

Comment: Also, what version should I be typing in for the line with the + in it? In the project settings, I saw 26.0.2 but that didn't help at all.

Comment: You could downgrade to 25, but you can search for "Android Support Library revisions"

Comment: Didn't seem to help. I am currently reinstalling SDK Tools right now, we will see what that does. If that doesn't do it then I will do a full reinstall of Android Studio and SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. in Android Studio, open Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
2. under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries causing problems
3. click "apply" to uninstall them
4. re-check the same libraries click "apply" to reinstall them
5. close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build

Comment: I've already tried this twice. I remembered after posting this that I had run out of hard drive space during install and it has caused errors, but after clearing some space and clicking retry the install completed so I assumed everything went okay. I'm in the middle of reinstalling Android Studio and SDK right now.

Comment: go to your sdk-tools folder and check if there is something.? if you are reinstalling it..it will solve the issue. your tools were missing

Comment: It was a package issue. Reinstalling fixed the issue. Now I'm running into issues with testing. My computer is a bit outdated so it cannot support Virtual Device emulation. Trying to get my phone setup for testing right now.

Comment: @Xandor: In the case when you're facing the same issue, try menu File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio before re-installing.

Answer (score 17):

Please be noted that support library from [revision 25.4.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-4-0) to the latest, we need to add google maven. As in the [release note says](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html):

> Important: The support libraries are now available through Google's
>   Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository
>   from the SDK Manager. For more information, see Support Library Setup.

So you need to add the google maven to your **root** build.gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Read more at [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: Is this something that is recommended or required? The support repository downloaded and installed correctly, so I'm not so sure this will help at all.

Comment: I'm reinstalling everything right now so I will attempt this afterwords, and will take note for practice, but right now I can't even compile a Hello World project.

Comment: this will solve the `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+` part.

Comment: It could be related to network connection or anti-virus or something blocking Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due of an interference with another library.
In my case I had to comment:

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)

Now it builds