# Install repository and sync project

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to make a new project for android wear but this error keeps showing up, I thought it was because I wasn't making new projects in the location I was making before but changing back the location didn't work.

but I when I am making a regular project for android phones there is no problem like this

[image]

Comment: post your sdk window screenshot

Comment: What happen when you click on the link "Install repository ans sync project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the recommended steps that was provided in the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665809/android-studio-default-project-fails-errorfailed-to-resolve-com-android-suppo).

> 1. in Android Studio, open Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
> 2. under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries causing problems
> 3. click "apply" to uninstall them
> 4. re-check the same libraries click "apply" to reinstall them
> 5. close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build

Need to take note the [update](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0) last July 2017 as well.

> Important: The support libraries are now available through Google's
>   Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository
>   from the SDK Manager. For more information, see [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

Here are some important points that you needed for google maven taken from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665809/android-studio-default-project-fails-errorfailed-to-resolve-com-android-suppo):

In your **root** build.gradle, you have to add the google maven just like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the 26.0.0 Versions didn't worked for me as well.
Try to use the version 25.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

first of all disable your Anti-Virus if have any.
secondly follow the steps

```
    In Android Studio, open Tool > Android > SDK Manager
    under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries that are previously   checked
    click "apply" to uninstall them

    re-check the same libraries click "apply" to reinstall them
    close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build
```

if this doesn't work then one who has a working A.S take his SDK files from App data